# Is there anyway to cut a slice of code from code object for execute in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

This is a continuation of the problem i asked before [Is there any special method on python class definition or metaclass about "After class is defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74370046/is-there-any-special-method-on-python-class-definition-or-metaclass-about-after)
To deal with circular reference, I implement a lazy import keeping type hints with above code:

```
import dataclasses
import inspect

lazy_chunks_key = '__lazy_chunks__'


@dataclasses.dataclass
class LazyChunk:
    _code: str
    _global: dict
    _local: dict

    def _load(self):
        if self._code:
            exec(self._code, self._global, self._local)
            self._code = ''

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        self._load()
        if item in self._local:
            return self._local[item]
        if item in self._global:
            return self._global[item]
        raise NameError(item)

    def __bool__(self):
        return False


def lazy_chunk():
    import re
    stack = inspect.stack()[1]
    with open(stack.filename, encoding='utf-8') as _src:
        src = iter(_src)
        for _ in range(stack.lineno): next(src)
        spacing, code = re.match(r"( *)([^ ].*)?", next(src)).groups()
        chunk_ind = len(spacing)
        code += '\n'
        while (line := next(src, None)) is not None:
            spacing, line_code = re.match(r"( *)([^ ].*)?", line).groups()
            if not line_code: continue
            if (_ind := len(spacing)) < chunk_ind: break
            code += ' ' * (_ind - chunk_ind) + line_code + '\n'
    frame = stack.frame
    frame.f_locals.setdefault(lazy_chunks_key, []).append(res := LazyChunk(code.strip(), frame.f_globals, frame.f_locals))
    return res
```

and in the structure factory, using the lazy chunk to get above type

```
def set_fields_from_annotations(cls: typing.Type[_CStruct]) -> typing.Type[_CStruct]:
    if not (annotations := getattr(cls, '__annotations__', None)): return cls
    global_namespace = getattr(sys.modules.get(cls.__module__, None), '__dict__', {})
    global_namespace[cls.__name__] = cls
    local_namespace = dict(vars(cls))

    def str_eval_with_lazy(v):
        if isinstance(v, str):
            for chunk in global_namespace.pop(lazy_chunks_key, ()):
                chunk._load()
            return eval(v, global_namespace, local_namespace)
        return v

    ... # passing `str_eval_with_lazy` to fields and call it to get actual type when it is needed
```

but when expanding my uses, cut codes from source file is not feasible. for example zipimport or import from pre compiled codes. to deal with this problem, is there any method to get module code object,get slice and run the slice in eval?

edit: an example usage of `lazy_chunk`

```
# tree.py
from .node import Node


@set_fields_from_annotations
class Node(ctypes.Structure):
    first_node: Node


# node.py
if lazy_chunk():
    from .tree import Tree


@set_fields_from_annotations
class Node(ctypes.Structure):
    tree: 'Tree'
    value: ctypes.c_uint
    key: ctypes.c_uint
    parent: 'ctypes.POINTER(Node)'
    child: 'ctypes.POINTER(Node)'
```

Comment: Please explain what you’re trying to do here at all‽

Comment: @deceze i am trying to get annotations type but prevent circular reference, an example code is added in the question